# Regular Expressions (.NET) - How can I match a pattern that contains a variable number of digits at the end of the string?

Tags: c#, regex

```
string src = "portfolio1, portfolio2, portfolio20, portfolio300";
```

I'd like to match all strings that are of the pattern @"portfolio\d"
where \d can be anywhere from 1-3 digits in length. I have read that the use of {a, b} should work, so I tried:

```
pattern = @"portfolio\d{1, 3}"
```

Searching in the string, src, for this pattern returned an empty set. the following patterns worked partially:

```
pattern = @"portfolio\d"
pattern = @"portfolio\d{1}"
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
pattern = @"portfolio\d{1,3}"
```

Note that you should not put a space in between the brackets, as you have in your example.  That's why it didn't work right.

Answer (score 0):

Running pattern "portfolio\d{1,3}" in Expresso, I get 4 matches on each of the portfolios. The space did it was the key.

Answer (score 0):

```
String pattern = @"^(?:(?:portfolio\d{1,3})(?:\x2C\s)*)+$";
```

My attempt. Will match any number of comma-seperated `portfolio\d{1,3}`'s

Comment: I attempted this version out of curiosity and was unable to get it to work. There was never a match.